# I need to write a query to display list of counts of employee in every state

Tags: mysql

The counts of all employees in every state is to be displayed. The query that i have written is:

```
Select count(distinct a.id)   
from address a   
Group by a.state;
```

Is there a more optimised solution for this?

There are two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4832 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dob` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58993 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. There is no relation between the `employee` and `address` table.

Comment: That query just tells you how many cities there are in the database.  @Wewestthemenance is right, there is no table assigning employees to cities

Comment: This query is not giving the desired output. The count that it is giving is wrong

Comment: That query is counting # number of cities within the address database.

Comment: But both id is auto incremented. how should i relate both the table.

Comment: er no.  You might study up a bit on relational databases.  http://www.agiledata.org/essays/relationalDatabases.html might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will not produce the correct output since there is no relation between the `employee` and `address` table.

You should add a column to the `employee` table that will reference the `id` in the `address` table:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD COLUMN address_id INT NOT NULL;
```

Then, to count the number of `employee`s per state:

```
SELECT 
    a.state,
    COALESCE(COUNT(e.id), 0) AS employee_count
FROM address a
LEFT JOIN employee e
    ON e.address_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.state
```

---

Additionally, you can add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_address(address_id)
REFERENCES address(id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Isn't the id (with autoincrement) simply a unique primary key?  No way can they be the same.  (I'd rather they be labeled `city_id` and `employee_id`, but thats just me.  )

Comment: @user0428, Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: @zipzit, do you mean that both `id`s that are `pk`s of each table be named as `city_id` and `employee_id`?

Comment: Yes, that's how I read it.  Its the auto_increment thing that has me baffled. With that auto increment, no way will the foreign key thing work.  And just to be clear, id is what exactly?  (employee_id tends to be a better functional description...)

Comment: Yeah, naming `id`s has been a quite a debate, but I also prefer the more descriptive one i.e. `employee_id`.

Comment: You said it correctly that there has to be an address_id (or city_id) field in the employee data table, but the content there will likely have to be manually entered, no way would you be able to `Poof it` into place.  This person is obviously learning relational data tables.  I'd rather see no foreign key stuff, instead coherent naming schemes that make it really clear... like employee_id and address_id as primary keys.  Makes the query much cleaner first time out.

Comment: Yes I agree both having same name was what confused me. But thats the question given to me so I can't do anything. Shall I proceed with the foreign key addition?

Comment: Ah, homework assignment?  Great way to learn this stuff.  Try it first with ids renamed, see that you get the results you expected.  Park it, then go to the foreign key stuff for step #2.

Comment: Na interview assignment. So can't afford to give wrong answer thats why being cautious. and its time bound so have to figure out quickly

Comment: I'm trying to find the format but its something like:  `address.id` (same as address_id ) or `employee.id`  Sorry my brain is mush.  The two id's are not the same thing.  I'm seeing this as a trick question, or just very poorly designed.

Comment: I would say poorly designed. I will write a note indicating that I have assumed that both ids are not same.